# Apache Derby Database Log Permissions

Tags: database, file-permissions, derby, ntfs, log-shipping

Log shipping transferring the log files under /database/log from the primary server to the secondary server was working fine. Someday the log files permission was changed and only Administrator had the rights now, causing the process to fail to copy over to the secondary server.

As usually I will login with local account as administrator to access the system and setup the log shipping, now it fails since the [log files generated only permits to Administrator ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybESS.png).

Why does the permissions change suddenly to only Administrator? Previously the log files was [assign to several account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLQJF.png). Is there a way to change the settings of the file permission to reset back as per multiple user instead of only Administrator upon file creation?

Changing from advanced security do not work as the log file will generate every 1MB file size, and only Administrator having the permissions.

Comment: I assume you've looked through http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.14/security/csecnetservfileperms.html and http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.14/ref/rrefproperdefaultfileperms.html for clues about what changes on your system might have affected this behavior?

Comment: Yes @BryanPendleton, I had found the solution from http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.14/security/csecnetservfileperms.html by configuring the property into derby.properties. Currently am investigating why this is happening. Thanks to your other link, I will test it out.